# Ошибка чтения файла при использовании функции feof (Си)

Tags: c

Написал программу, считающую количество строк в текстовом файле.

Строки она считает правильно, однако после того, как я добавил проверку на ошибку чтения файла, программа почему-то выводит сообщение об ошибке 47 раз, а затем всё равно выводит правильный результат (к слову, в файле всего 25 символов (не считая каких-либо управляющих символов типа \n) и 21 строка). В чём проблема?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("C:/c/fff.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        puts("Error opening file.");
    }

    int lines = 1;
    while(!feof(file)) {    // цикл, считающий кол-во строк в файле
        if(feof(file) == 0) {       // проверка на ошибку чтения файла
            puts("Error reading.");
        }
        if(fgetc(file) == '\n') {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    printf("%i", lines);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `feof` проверяет достигнут ли конец файла. Возвращает 0 если **не** достигнут и не ноль, в противном случае.

Из чего следует, что строчка `if(feof(file) == 0)` внутри `while(!feof(file))` абсолютно бессмысленна. Если вы зашли внутрь `while`, то конец файла ещё не достигнут.

Comment: Только что понял, что ошибка простая.

Comment: Добавил ответ на вопрос, так будет корректно сделать проверку?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что правильная проверка на ошибку чтения файла должна выглядеть так.

```
int c;
while(!feof(file)) {    // цикл, считающий кол-во строк в файле
    c = fgetc(file);
    if(c == '\n') {
        lines++;
    }
}
if(c == EOF && feof(file) == 0) {   // проверка на ошибку чтения файла
    puts("Error reading");
}
```

Comment: Замечание 1 - зачем вам по окончании файла сообщать, что произошла ошибка чтения? Это не ошибка - вы добрались, **как и ожидали**, до конца. Вы же **всегда** собираетесь выводить сообщение об ошибке - зачем? И второе - в вашем случае это неважно, но на потом :) учтите, что `feof` сообщит о конце файла **после** попытки чтения за концом. Так что внутри `while(`feof(f))` будет одна попытка чтения за концом файла - иногда это важно.

Comment: К замечанию 1 - так ведь функция feof возвращает 0 только в случае, если не достигнут конец файла (ошибка чтения). Поэтому после окончания цикла проверяется, не вернёт ли feof 0, и сообщение об ошибке выводится только если вернёт. Программа работает правильно. Но, может, я чего-то всё же недопонял.